# How to encrypt data in objective-c using a public key generated from php script

Tags: php, cocoa, public-key-encryption

I've looked around and found scant information on encryption on Mac OS X.  It seems like OpenSSL support is deprecated in newer version of Mac OS X. I need to be able to support from 10.5 and up.  Here's my problem:

I have a public and private key pair generate on our licensing server using php (code shown below)

```
$dn = array(configs....);
$privkey = openssl_pkey_new();

$csr = openssl_csr_new($dn, $privkey);

$sscert = openssl_csr_sign($csr, null, $privkey, $term);

openssl_x509_export($sscert, $publickey);
openssl_pkey_export($privkey, $privatekey, "somepassphrase");

//base64 encode the keys
$privatekey = base64_encode($privatekey);
$publickey = base64_encode($publickey);
```

The base64 encoded private key is stored in a secure location on one of our servers and the base64 encoded public key is written to a file for download by our users.  The file is loaded into a desktop application for MacOS X written in cocoa, which base64 decodes the public key.  Until this step is good.  However, I want to then encrypt data with the public key and send it to our license server.  Does anyone know how I can use this public key to encrypt data in cocoa and what is the "best" practice method?  Any examples or tips would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not so much OpenSSL that is deprecated on the Mac but merely the OpenSSL libraries that are **provided** by OS X are deprecated. Nothing stops you from compiling your own OpenSSL and use it in your app by statically linking to it:

> Although OpenSSL is commonly used in the open source community,
>   OpenSSL does not provide a stable API from version to version. For
>   this reason, although OS X provides OpenSSL libraries, the OpenSSL
>   libraries in OS X are deprecated, and OpenSSL has never been provided
>   as part of iOS. Use of the OS X OpenSSL libraries by apps is strongly
>   discouraged.
>
> If your app depends on OpenSSL, you should compile OpenSSL yourself
>   and statically link a known version of OpenSSL into your app. This use
>   of OpenSSL is possible on both OS X and iOS. However, unless you are
>   trying to maintain source compatibility with an existing open source
>   project, you should generally use a different API.
>
> Common Crypto and Security Transforms are the recommended alternatives
>   for general encryption. CFNetwork and Secure Transport are the
>   recommended alternatives for secure communications.

In other words: It is still fine to use OpenSSL in your OS X app - just don't rely on the bundled OpenSSL anymore. Alternatively, you can make use of OS X' [Security Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Reference/SecurityFrameworkReference/_index.html): It is capable of handling X.509 public key encryption which you seem to be doing as well.

Source: [Cocoa Cryptographic Services Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/cryptoservices/GeneralPurposeCrypto/GeneralPurposeCrypto.html)

Comment: Thank you that really helped clarify my issue.  I will look into the security framework.